# Supress ld symbol not found error to resolve later in runtime

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld

I have the following library:

`shared4.c`:

```
int get_another_int(void){
    return 10;
}
```

And the binary:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int get_another_int(void);

int main(void){
    void *handle = dlopen("/home/me/c/build/libshar4.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if(!handle){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("handle = %p\n", handle);
    printf("another_int = %d\n", get_another_int());
}
```

I did not link the binary with the library and added an `ld` option to ignore the symbol not found error:

```
-Wl,-z,lazy -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all
```

With such options the binary compiled and linked "fine".

The `plt` section looks as follows:

```
$ objdump -d -j .plt ./build/bin_shared 

./build/bin_shared:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .plt:

00000000000005e0 <.plt>:
 5e0:   ff 35 22 0a 20 00       pushq  0x200a22(%rip)        # 201008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 5e6:   ff 25 24 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a24(%rip)        # 201010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 5ec:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
        ...

0000000000000600 <dlopen@plt>:
 600:   ff 25 1a 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a1a(%rip)        # 201020 <dlopen@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 606:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
 60b:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   5e0 <.plt>

0000000000000610 <__printf_chk@plt>:
 610:   ff 25 12 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a12(%rip)        # 201028 <__printf_chk@GLIBC_2.3.4>
 616:   68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
 61b:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   5e0 <.plt>

0000000000000620 <exit@plt>:
 620:   ff 25 0a 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a0a(%rip)        # 201030 <exit@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 626:   68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
 62b:   e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmpq   5e0 <.plt>
```

I examined the `objdump` and noticed the following fragment of `main`:

```
 66b:   e8 a0 ff ff ff          callq  610 <__printf_chk@plt>
 670:   e8 7b ff ff ff          callq  5f0 <.plt+0x10>
```

But the application failed to start with the following error:

```
$ ./build/bin_shared 
./build/bin_shared: error while loading shared libraries: unexpected PLT reloc type 0x00
```

I looked at all relocation types:

```
$ objdump -R ./build/bin_shared 

./build/bin_shared:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000200dd8 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x00000000000007a0
0000000000200de0 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000000760
0000000000201040 R_X86_64_RELATIVE  *ABS*+0x0000000000201040
0000000000200fd8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000200fe0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000200fe8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __gmon_start__
0000000000200ff0 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000200ff8 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000201020 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  dlopen@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000201028 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  __printf_chk@GLIBC_2.3.4
0000000000201030 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  exit@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000 R_X86_64_NONE     *ABS*                    //<---- This relocation
```

**Is there a way to workaround this and make symbols from a library loaded with `dlopen`, but not linked with `ld` during the link time to be available for dynamic linker so the application I showed above would run as expected?**

Comment: The "unexpected PLT reloc type" is probably symptom of something else wrong with the build. By the way you should use =ignore-in-object-files, not =ignore-all.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Just tried to replace `ignore-all`, but got same result. Regarding "unexpected PLT reloc type" it is probably that during linking the executable the symbol `get_another_int` was not found (at least there was a relevant entry in the relocation table I showed in the question)

Comment: You should add the full command line of the commands you use to produce both the shared library and the binary.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The full list of compiler flags are `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files -Wl,-z,lazy -Warray-bounds -Wextra -Wall -g3 -O3 -D_GNU_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to workaround this

The linker *must* know that the symbol will be coming from some shared library, and needs to know what *kind* of symbol this is, in order to properly build a dynamic symbol reference for that symbol in the main executable.

Since you don't want to (or can't) provide `libshar4.so` at link time, your other option is to *pretend* that some other library that you *do* link against provides this symbol.

For example, since you use `dlopen`, you could create a `dlopen_stub.so`, which provides both `dlopen` *and* `get_another_int` (the actual implementation of either function in the stub can be empty), set the `SONAME` of this stub library to `libdl.so.2` (or whatever `SONAME` your real `libdl.so` uses), and link your binary with that stub (instead of linking with `-ldl`).

At runtime, provided that `LD_BIND_NOW` is *not* in effect, the binary will not attempt to resolve `get_another_int` until after you've loaded `libshar4.so`, and by that time the symbol will be available.